# Static UIImageView at top of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to add a static `UIImageView` that will "stick" to the `UINavigationBar` when scrolling through a `UITableView`?

In the image below, the gray image would essentially stick to the `UINavigationBar` so that it would be visible in that exact same position anywhere on the screen.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use an `UIViewController` instead of an `UITableViewController` an add your `UIImageView` as a subview to the main view?

Comment: Why not make it a sibling of the table view by adding it as a subview of the table views superview? Otherwise a section header if you only have one section.

Comment: @Wain ahhh that's perfect, because I do in fact only have one section. How might I go about changing the section header to an image, though? Usually it's text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the delegate method `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and supply an image view (or an image view inside another view if you need some padding round the edges). This is assuming that you only have one section.

If you have multiple sections you would either need to add the image view as a subview of the table views superview or use `contentInset` and tamper with the scrolling.